# ANCOVA in WRS2 in R: what is producing row.names error?

Tags: r, analysis

I am attempting to run a robust `ANCOVA` from package `WRS2` on the dataframe `NewKDF` (see below) where `COND = 2` group factor, `HTAC` = continuous numeric covariate and `BDD` = continuous dependent variable.

```
> head(NewKDF)
#COND HTAC BDD
#1    1   10   2
#2    2   10   6
#3    1    8   0
#4    1   15   2
#5    1   10   1
#6    2    7   2
> tail(NewKDF)
#COND HTAC BDD
#32    1   35  10
#33    2   18   5
#34    1   35   6
#35    2   10   7
#36    2    7   2
#37    1   15   4

> ancova(BDD ~ COND + HTAC, data=NewKDF)
Call:
ancova(formula = BDD ~ COND + HTAC, data = NewKDF)
```

Which keeps producing the following error:

> Error in row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
>       duplicate row.names are not allowed
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>       non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘HTAC = 11’

I have checked the dataframe in R's data error and also used:

```
> attributes(NewKDF)
$names
[1] "COND" "HTAC" "BDD" 

$row.names
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

I can't see any way there are duplicate row names - am I missing something?

Comment: I am getting the same error with another dataset. Did you ever find a solution?